# Inserting data into the database in SQLite using getter and setter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an application that inserts data into the database. The table is created but nothing gets inserted into the database and I do not get any error. I have tried to look at the codes line by line but I cannot spot anything wrong. When I click on the save button it closes unexpectedly.

Insert method in the TreatmentRepo class

```
        public void insert(Treatment treatment) {

    //Open connection to write data
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String query = "select * from Treatment";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    int  count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(Treatment.KEY_TreatmentID, count);
    values.put(Treatment.KEY_TreatmentNumber, treatment.getEditTextTreatmentNumber());
    values.put(Treatment.KEY_TreatmentType, treatment.getEditTextTreatmentType());
    values.put(Treatment.KEY_TreatmentName, treatment.getEditTextTreatmentName());

    db.insert(Treatment.TABLE, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

}
```

This is my onClick method

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnSave) {
        TreatmentRepo repo = new TreatmentRepo(this);


        editTextTreatmentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTreatmentName);
        editTextTreatmentType = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTreatmentType);
        editTextTreatmentNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTreatmentNumber);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);

        int treatmentNumber = Integer.parseInt(editTextTreatmentNumber.getText().toString());
        String treatmentType = editTextTreatmentType.getText().toString();
        String treatmentName = editTextTreatmentName.getText().toString();

        Treatment treatment = new Treatment();
        treatment.setEditTextTreatmentNumber(treatmentNumber);
        treatment.setEditTextTreatmentName(treatmentName);
        treatment.setEditTextTreatmentType(treatmentType);

        repo.insert(treatment);

        Toast.makeText(this, "New Treatment Insert", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, view_treatment_entry.class));
}
}
```

Treatment

```
public class Treatment {


    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE = "Treatment";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_TreatmentID = "TreatmentId";
    public static final String KEY_TreatmentName = "TreatmentName";
    public static final String KEY_TreatmentType = "TreatmentType";
    public static final String KEY_TreatmentNumber = "TreatmentNumber";

    // property help us to keep data
    public int treatment_ID;
    public String editTextTreatmentName;
    public String editTextTreatmentType;
    public int editTextTreatmentNumber;


    public int getEditTextTreatmentNumber() {
        return editTextTreatmentNumber;
    }

    public void setEditTextTreatmentNumber(int editTextTreatmentNumber) {
        this.editTextTreatmentNumber = editTextTreatmentNumber;
    }

    public String getEditTextTreatmentName() {
        return editTextTreatmentName;
    }

    public void setEditTextTreatmentName(String editTextTreatmentName) {
        this.editTextTreatmentName = editTextTreatmentName;
    }

    public String getEditTextTreatmentType() {
        return editTextTreatmentType;
    }

    public void setEditTextTreatmentType(String editTextTreatmentType) {
        this.editTextTreatmentType = editTextTreatmentType;
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:context="com.instinctcoder.sqlitedb.StudentDetail$PlaceholderFragment"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Treatment Name"
            android:id="@+id/treatmentName"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Treatment Type"
            android:id="@+id/treatmentType"
            android:layout_below="@+id/treatmentName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Treatment Number"
            android:id="@+id/treatmentNumber"
            android:layout_below="@+id/treatmentType"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="29dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTreatmentName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/treatmentType"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/treatmentName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTreatmentType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/treatmentNumber"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextTreatmentName"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextTreatmentName"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/treatmentName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textShortMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editTextTreatmentNumber"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/treatmentNumber"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextTreatmentType"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextTreatmentType"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextTreatmentType"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextTreatmentType" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnClose"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnSave" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add your logcat of error

Comment: There is no error in the logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are missing some important information to help you problem solve this. A few things that would be needed to get to the bottom of this without guessing and checking.

- Your SQLiteOpenHelper class and snippet of newing it up to confirm proper Context usage
- Your Create SQL statement to ensure that that data types expected match int, String, int, String the way you are inserting.
- Does your DB open return the db properly
- Does your first Select query return a count properly

But without having that info I would say you could try a couple of things.
First see if the insert works with hard coded values to eliminate the potential of bad values and eliminate the potential of the DB being unavailable due to the first query. So I would comment out the rawQuery and hard code an insert and then different method hard code a select all to see if it went in properly.

Also, you are not using your insert primary id, not sure if that was intentional or not.

So best I can do for you for now, is show you a working example with generic management of tables and SQL Opening as I don't like to make openers for each project so I came up with a A35SQLUtil lib that I made for this purpose. A35 being my personal company abbreviation App Studio 35.

Feel free to take any of the below examples and run with them, or try and of the ideas above to troubleshoot or supply additional info. Hope this helped.

A lot of times I will make a singleton SQLOpenHelper that requires the context of the caller and then a dataContext for the specific table elements and of course a TableModel to represent the columns and SQL scripts for managing it. An insert would look something like:

```
public class OrderDataContext {

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MEMBERS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private static final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + OrderDataContext.class.getSimpleName();


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CONSTRUCTOR
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private OrderDataContext(){}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CRUD OPERATIONS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static long insertNewOrder(OrderModel model, Context context){
    long primaryKey = -1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try{
        db = A35DBHelper.openDatabase(context);
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put(OrdersTable.COLUMN_ORDER_NUMBER, model.getID());
        initialValues.put(OrdersTable.COLUMN_VIN, model.getVIN());
        initialValues.put(OrdersTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT_DATE,  model.getCreatedAtDate());
        initialValues.put(OrdersTable.COLUMN_IMAGE_COUNT, model.getImageCount());
        initialValues.put(OrdersTable.COLUMN_DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_URL, model.getDefaultThumbnailUrl());

        primaryKey = db.insert(OrdersTable.TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        A35Log.e(TAG, "Failed to insert order: " + ex.getMessage());

    }

    A35DBHelper.closeDatabase(db);
    return  primaryKey;
}
```

}
}

The SQLHelper would look like:

```
public final class A35DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = A35DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private static int sDatabaseVersion;
private static String sDatabaseName = null;
private static List<Class<? extends IA35Table>> sTables;

private A35DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context.getApplicationContext(), sDatabaseName, (CursorFactory)null, sDatabaseVersion);
}

public static void initialize(String databaseName, int databaseVersion, Class<? extends IA35Table> table) {
    ArrayList tables = new ArrayList();
    tables.add(table);
    initialize(databaseName, databaseVersion, (List)tables);
}

public static void initialize(String databaseName, int databaseVersion, List<Class<? extends IA35Table>> tables) {
    sDatabaseName = databaseName;
    sDatabaseVersion = databaseVersion;
    sTables = tables;
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    Iterator i = sTables.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Class table = (Class)i.next();

        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(((IA35Table)table.newInstance()).getCreateTableScript());
        } catch (Exception var5) {
            Log.e(TAG, var5.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Iterator i = sTables.iterator();

    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Class table = (Class)i.next();

        try {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(((IA35Table)table.newInstance()).getUpgradeTableScript());
        } catch (Exception var7) {
            Log.e(TAG, var7.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase(Context context) throws Exception {
    return getA35DBHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
}

public static void closeDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    CloseableUtil.close(TAG, db);
}

public static Cursor executeSelectQueryForCursor(Context context, String sqlScript) throws Exception {
    SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = getA35DBHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = readableDatabase.rawQuery(sqlScript, (String[])null);
    return cursor;
}

public static void executeWriteQuery(Context context, String sqlScript) throws Exception {
    SQLiteDatabase writeSqLiteDatabase = getA35DBHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
    writeSqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlScript);
    CloseableUtil.close(TAG, writeSqLiteDatabase);
}

public static void closeCursor(String tag, Closeable closeable) {
    CloseableUtil.close(tag, closeable);
}

private static A35DBHelper getA35DBHelper(Context context) throws Exception {
    try {
        return new A35DBHelper(context);
    } catch (Exception var2) {
        throw new Exception("MUST call A35DBHelper.initialize before using the helper methods");
    }
}
```

}

Then my Table Model would look like:

```
public class OrdersTable implements IA35Table {

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MEMBERS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private static final String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + OrdersTable.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ordersTable";
public static final String COLUMN_PRIMARY_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_ORDER_NUMBER = "orderNumber";
public static final String COLUMN_VIN = "vin";
public static final String COLUMN_CREATED_AT_DATE = "createdAtDate";
public static final String COLUMN_IMAGE_COUNT = "imageCount";
public static final String COLUMN_DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_URL = "defaultThumbnailUrl";
public static String columns[] = {
        OrdersTable.COLUMN_PRIMARY_ID,
        OrdersTable.COLUMN_REPAIR_ORDER_NUMBER,
        OrdersTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT_DATE
};


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// IA35TABLE OVERRIDES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public String getCreateTableScript() {
    A35SQLHelper.CreateTableStatement createTableStatement = new A35SQLHelper.CreateTableStatement(TABLE_NAME);

    createTableStatement.addColumnAsIntPrimaryKey(COLUMN_PRIMARY_ID);
    createTableStatement.addColumn(A35SQLHelper.ColumnType.TEXT, COLUMN_REPAIR_ORDER_NUMBER, false, null);
    createTableStatement.addColumn(A35SQLHelper.ColumnType.TEXT, COLUMN_VIN, false, null);
    createTableStatement.addColumn(A35SQLHelper.ColumnType.TEXT, COLUMN_CREATED_AT_DATE, false, null);
    createTableStatement.addColumn(A35SQLHelper.ColumnType.INTEGER, COLUMN_IMAGE_COUNT, false, null);
    createTableStatement.addColumn(A35SQLHelper.ColumnType.TEXT, COLUMN_DEFAULT_THUMBNAIL_URL, false, null);

    String createTableScript = createTableStatement.generateSQL();
    A35Log.d(TAG, "Creating " + TABLE_NAME + " Table. Query: " + createTableScript);

    return createTableScript;

}
@Override
public String getUpgradeTableScript() {
    //Currently, I am dropping date and create the table again. But If required in future,
    //I will need to handle the data migration operations.
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "; ");
    sb.append(getCreateTableScript());
    A35Log.d(TAG, "Dropping " + TABLE_NAME + " Table. Query: " + sb.toString());

    return sb.toString();

}
```

}

Lastly, I new up my instance generically in the Application file like so:

```
public class A35Application extends Application {

/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MEMBERS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private final static String TAG = Globals.SEARCH_STRING + A35Application.class.getSimpleName();
private static final String A35_ORDER_DB_NAME = "a35_orders_db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// LIFECYCLE OVERRIDES
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate()");
    setup();

}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PUBLIC METHODS
*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void setup() {
    A35Log.v(TAG, "setup()");
    setCurrentEnvironment(A35Environment.Env.PRD);
    setupCustomFonts();
    **setupDatabase();**
    setupLogging();
    startAnalyticsReporting();
    if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        startCrashReporting();

    }

}


/*///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PRIVATE METHODS
*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void setupDatabase(){
    A35Log.v(TAG, "setupDatabase()");
    A35DBHelper.initialize(A35_ORDERS_DB_NAME, DB_VERSION, getDBTables());

}
private ArrayList<Class<? extends IA35Table>> getDBTables() {
    ArrayList<Class<? extends IA35Table>> tables = new ArrayList<>();

    tables.add(SessionTable.class);
    tables.add(ServicesTable.class);
    tables.add(OrdersTable.class);
    tables.add(ImagesToUploadTable.class);
    tables.add(VideosToUploadTable.class);
    tables.add(AudiosToUploadTable.class);

    return tables;
}
```

}

Then for thoroughness here is the interface

```
public interface IA35Table {
 String getCreateTableScript();
 String getUpgradeTableScript();
}
```

and close util

```
public class CloseableUtil {
public CloseableUtil() {
}

public static void close(@NonNull String tag, @Nullable Closeable closeable) {
    if(closeable != null) {
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            Log.e(tag, "Unable to close: " + closeable, var3);
        }
    }

}

public static void closeWithThrowIOException(@Nullable Closeable closeable) throws IOException {
    if(closeable != null) {
        closeable.close();
    }

}
```

}